# Javascript: /e modifier for RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, url, arithmetic-expressions

Is there something like [Perls /e modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2FPATTERN%2FREPLACEMENT%2Fmsixpodualgcer) in JavaScript to integrate simple arithmetic like multiplication and addition to a regular expression that is evaluated with the [RegExp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)?

I want to transfer a pattern for URL generation which may includes concatenation, multiplication and division of strings and replaced integer variables that is more secure than to transfer and evaluate Javascript code.

Comment: Nope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters

Comment: Is there maybe any other kind of pattern instead of regular expressions that allows such (nearly) limited operations?

Comment: What you you try to do that's in need of a typical Perl `s///e` construct ? Can you show an example before / after ? Are you dynamically generating a regex, or modifying a regex ?

Comment: Actually what you're asking for is not more secure than transferring and evaluating javascript code. It IS transferring and evaluating JavaScript code albeit in a limited context. For something truly more secure you can combine @Sam's answer with a lookup table of different pre-defined functions to be called. For example you can send `{url: '...', processor: 'frobnicate'}` and validate that `frobnicate` is a valid processor then call it as your callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you desire is achieved by passing a callback function to [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

---

For example, in Perl:

```
my $result = '1 foo 2 bar 3' =~ s/\d+/ $& * 2 /erg;
```

And in Javascript:

```
var result = '1 foo 2 bar 3'.replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
    return match * 2;
});
```

Both `result`s will equal:

```
2 foo 4 bar 6
```

---

Reading the full documentation of `.replace()` will show extra parameters that can be passed to the callback function, including captured groups if necessary.

Comment: That's not a solution and does not answer the question. I have to transfer the arithmetic expression as well and I am looking for a more secure way than to send JavaScript - It would be a big security hole to execute JavaScript from an insecure source.

Comment: @Ted Barth, This is a solution, and it does answer the question. This is exactly the same thing as `/e`. It's just a little shorter to type in Perl.

Comment: The next time I will write a question five hundred words long, only to include all side-conditions in the same sentence - It's hard to write a question on SO that is interpreted as you want. The checkmark goes to you! :D